# Free GUI website builder for Windows 10

Tags: windows, gratis, web-development, gui, gui-builder

I'm looking for a GUI webpage builder, something similar to [Pinegrow](http://pinegrow.com/). My requirements for builder are:

- Drag and drop GUI interface
- Gratis
- Easy to use
- Being updated frequently
- Uses Bootstrap, Zurb Framework, or another popular framework (I don't want a framework that is just used by the builder itself)
- Able to be run offline (this of course excludes online builders)
- Runs on Windows 10

Comment: What's wrong with Pinegrow?

Comment: @Markasoftware It's not gratis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I have been using an application called Pingendo. It's a great program for creating simple webpages but I would like something a little more powerful like Pinegrow. It meets all my requirements.

## [Pingendo](http://pingendo.com/)

> The simplest app for Bootstrap prototyping
>
> [image: Pingendo UI]

Comment: Does it run on windows?

Comment: @beppe9000 It sure does, [32bit](http://download.pingendo.com/v3/pingendo-win32.zip) & [64bit](http://download.pingendo.com/v3/pingendo-win64.zip)

Comment: Thanks, I was misled by the screenshot into believing otherwise.

Comment: @beppe9000 Ya, I just used the screenshot from the website but it still is compatible with Windows and Linux