# Webpage editor (wysiwyg) replacing Frontpage

Tags: windows, web-development, wysiwyg

I have a friend that is not the most techy of people.
He is editing a homepage with about 100 pages - almost pure html.

So far he has been working in **[FrontPage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage)**

However, his old machine is dying and FrontPage does not go well with windows 10. So it is time to find the replacement.

**Can you recommend:**

- a web-page-editor with a simple user interface
- it should be a download and install program
- it must still be active - many out there are discontinued
- if possible with a Danish UI

It should preferably be freeware/opensoure
It should focus on wysiwyg - he does not code

He uses the build in 'FrontPage Server Extension' when putting his work online. So if possible the program should include a  'commit' / 'publish' button (build in ftp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free GUI website builder for Windows 10](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24946/free-gui-website-builder-for-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Pingendo. It's an easy to use WYSIWYG web page editor with an extremely simple interface. It's a program that you download and install yourself where you can use it offline. This program is still in active development currently working on Bootstrap 4.0 support.

## [Pingendo](http://pingendo.com/)

> Pingendo helps you authoring HTML5 and CSS3 web pages. Bootstrap editor.
>
> - Built for productivity - Create quality HTML prototypes quickly, using popular open source tools like Bootstrap, LESS, Fontawesome and
>     more.
> - Design and code - Work visually and with sources simultaneously, with no need to export.
> - Developer friendly - Easily integrates into developers' toolsets (Git, text editors, etc.) & works with plain HTML and LESS files.
> - Vanilla - Generate only standard Bootstrap 3.3 HTML and LESS markup.
>
> [image: Pingendo UI]